# How to delete a selected row from datagridview?

Tags: c#, exception

```
if (dgvProductCatalog.Rows.Count > 1 && dgvProductCatalog.SelectedRows[0].Index != dgvProductCatalog.Rows.Count - 1)

{
 cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Products WHERE ProductId= " + dgvProductCatalog.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + " " , connection);
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    dgvProductCatalog.Rows.RemoveAt(dgvProductCatalog.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");
                    DisplayData();
                    ClearData();
                }
}
```

I am using the above piece of code on a button click to delete a selected row but i am getting 
"**System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.**" What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use currentRow instead

```
dgvProductCatalog.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value
```

Then

```
dgvProductCatalog.Rows.RemoveAt(dgvProductCatalog.CurrentRow.Index)
```

or

```
dgvProductCatalog.Rows.RemoveAt(dgvProductCatalog.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex)
```

Also while you are at it, I would change this line too

```
if (dgvProductCatalog.Rows.Count > 1 && dgvProductCatalog.SelectedCells.count > 0)
```

My guess is the if statement above is running when the selectedCells.Count = -1

Lastly, as just a suggestion, instead of

```
WHERE ProductId= " + Cell.Value + " "
```

I would use

```
WHERE ProductId='" + Cell.Value + "'"
```

The ' is important for mitigating possible errors.